# Open iframe in new tab, if iframe page using _parent target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe from other site for example iframedomain.com (I can't control this domain) and my site is for example mydomain.com. I am using this code on my site:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="iframedomain.com/iframe.html"></iframe>
```

On iframedomain.com using _parent target for links and links opening in same windows.

I want to open this links in new tab is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to open the links within the iframe in a new tab?

Comment: yes, but I can't change code on iframedomain.com

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I understood your request.

Comment: thanks I hope someone will help me, if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Your links inside the iframe should use `target="_blank"`

Comment: He doesn't control the domain within the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

This will make it so when you click on the iframe it will load the src into the current tab.

```
document.getElementById("iframeID").addEventListener("click",function(){
   window.location.href=this.getAttribute("src");
},false);
```

This will make it so when you click on the iframe it will load the src into a new tab.

```
document.getElementById("iframeID").addEventListener("click",function(){
   window.open(this.getAttribute("src"),'_blank');
},false);
```

if you want to modify html inside the iframe you would first want to get access to the document the iframe has loaded.

```
var f = document.getElementById('iframeID');
var fcw = (f.contentWindow) ? f.contentWindow : (f.contentDocument.document) ? f.contentDocument.document : f.contentDocument;
fcw.document.open();
//do stuff to document.
fcw.document.close();
```

after getting access to the IFrame DOM you can modify the DOM as needed. For example have your javascript search the DOM for all `a` tags and add the attribute `TARGET` with the value `_blank`

Comment: So man I feel this code will work but I think I am doing wrong..

this code would work?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="iframeID" src="iframe.html"></iframe>


<script>
document.getElementById("iframeID").addEventListener("click",function(){
   window.open(this.getAttribute("src"),'_blank');
},false);

</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: see where i have `iframeID` just set that to what ever the id is of your target iframe. You will see that you can target the iframe dom with `fcw.document` based on the code i provided.

Comment: for example try `fcw.document.write("hello world");` you will see the dom for the iframe will change to the text `hello world`.